# to make pydata handle string columns

Tags: pandas, pytables

I have a dataframe that has a few columns with floats and a few columns that are string. All columns have `nan`. The string columns have either strings or `nan` which appear to have a type `float`. When I try to 'df.to_hdf' to store the dataframe, I get the following error:

`your performance may suffer as PyTables will pickle object types that it cannot
map directly to c-types [inferred_type->mixed,key->block0_values] [items->['operation', 'snl_datasource_period', 'ticker', 'cusip', 'end_fisca_perio_date', 'fiscal_period', 'finan_repor_curre_code', 'earni_relea_date', 'finan_perio_begin_on']]`

How can I work around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fill each column with the appropriate missing value.  E.g.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

col1 = [1.0, np.nan, 3.0]
col2 = ['one', np.nan, 'three']

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(col1=col1, col2=col2))
df['col1'] = df['col1'].fillna(0.0)
df['col2'] = df['col2'].fillna('')

df.to_hdf('eg.hdf', 'eg')
```

Comment: In fact it isn't necessary to fill the float column as it is all the same type.  Only a object column with NaNs in it would need filling (in this case col2)

Comment: yes, it works. but the `to_hdf` doesn't appear to compress no matter what compression level or algo used.

Comment: Are you sure you just aren't seeing a reduction in size because your data isn't big enough or isn't compressible.  HDF5 has a much larger format overhead than something like gzip.  It is designed for compressing MB/GB/TB.  You can see if the compression filters have been applied with `h5ls -v eg.hdf/eg | grep Filter`, if you saved with `df.to_hdf('eg.hdf', 'eg', complevel=9, complib='zlib')`